# Rearranging the equation of a line and using it to find the vector equation of another line.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

So I have to rearrange the equation of line 1 $2x+8 = y-1 = -2-2z$ to get it in the form

$$\frac{x - x0}{2} = \frac{y - y0}{2} = \frac{z - z0}{2}$$

to which I get

$$\frac{x-8}2 = y+1 = \frac{z+2}{-2}$$

But from there I need to find the vector equation of another line with the point $(1,2,-1)$ and also parallel to line 1 I above.

I want to know how to find the vector equation using this given information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to be careful when rearranging the initial equations to obtain the desired form. It is not possible to arrive to the formulas you wrote (neither the one with all denominators equal to 2 nor the other one).

The formula of a line is
$$\frac{x - x0}{a} = \frac{y - y0}{b} = \frac{z - z0}{c},$$
$(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ being a point of the line and $(a,b,c)$ a directional vector for it.

In order to keep the equalities true, you need to multiply both numerator and denominator by the same constant. For instance:
$$2x +8 = \frac{2x+8}{1} = \frac{x+4}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{x-(-4)}{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
where $x_0=-4$ and $a=\frac12$. Try analogously with the other two.

Once you have $(a,b,c)$, you can compute your second line. In fact, since it has to be parallel to the first one, they both share the same vector. Use my general formula above, with theat vector and the given point $(1,2,-1)$.

Comment: Can I ask how you divided by 1 and then divided by two later and then changed it to a negative number? Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @R.Mercy You can always multiply or divide any quantity (known or unknown) by 1 and it will remain the same; that is, $m = 1\cdot m = m\cdot 1 = \frac{m}{1}$. Note also that $$mx+n = \frac{m p x+np}{p}$$ and $$mx+n = \frac{\frac{m}{p} x+\frac{n}{p}}{\frac{1}{p}}$$ for any nonzero $p\in\mathbb{R}.$